# Mobile web app with out any javascript or JQuery?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering if there is a framework to develop mobile web applications which does not use javascript or jquery. Our client do not want to use any javascript or jquery in the projects. But when i look around for mobile web solutions, i see lots of jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "mobile" website does not require any special frameworks. You just have to design the site (HTML+CSS) so that it looks great on the smaller screens. Other than that it is the same old HTML forms as was 10 years ago (with the exception that you can use the new fancy HTML5 input types like calendar out of the box).

But you should dig deeper for the reasoning of "no JavaScript" since without it you will have to resort to whole page refreshes even for very small things (like 'hide field X when you choose USA in the address') and that will very negatively impact performance, especially on mobile devices where the network is slower.

Comment: So just fix height and width that almost matches to mobile. And work on CSS accordingly right ?. Yes, no java script will be a pain.... but as of now we have no choice...

Comment: Review the `viewport` meta header - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag when specifying the width.

Answer (score 1):

If you use mobile MVC views, why use a framework?  Why not create your own minimalist design that doesn't incorporate a lot of those features, but has the basic core HTML to define your user interface, and just allow the application to postback to the server?  That would work well, and be efficient in mobile.